# netbeans mass ftp

Tags: netbeans, ftp

I am familiar with the ftp in netbeans and I send my projects to multiple servers, so I have multiple remote connections. When a change is made it takes a while to reconfigure the project to the next remote connection and send the project to the location on the server. Also, each remote connection setup is the exact same, except for the ip address of course.

I am wondering, is there a way to do a mass ftp to all of my remote connections at once?

or

Is there a plugin for netbeans that will allow for this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm... I'm having same issue.. Still no answer here..

Answer (score 0):

The upload host depends on the actual run configuration. You can use different **run configurations** to switch easily between different server settings. But you can only use one configuration at the same time.

To upload your files to different hosts add configurations for each host. Change the configuration in the toolbar under the menubar and upload again all files)

[image]